# How to create a read only email account on postfix mail server?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, permissions

I need to create a read only email account in a postfix mail system. Could anyone help me how to do this on a postfix systems ?

Your help is greatly appreciated !

Regards,
Karthick

Answer (score 1):

Postfix is just the mail transfer agent, to make a maibox read-only requires messing with the mail store or the mail access agent (the POP or IMAP server). Off the top of my head, I don't remember any that allows "read-only" (and it makes litle sense, how to mark messages as read or answered?). POP is probably hopeless, but perhaps IMAP has a way of marking messages read-only, would have to check the RFC.

Isn't it enough to route the mail to be protected to a file, or another address *without* mail reading privileges, for safekeeping? You can set up aliases to send mail directed to `bob` to go to `bob` and `bob-save`.